# How to add frame to NSImage?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have `NSImage`s:

```
NSImage[2] images;
```

How to make animated GIF NSImage with 2 frames?

How to convert it in NSData and save animated GIF on disk?

Comment: How to not ask one similar question after another after another regarding GIF?  How to run a search before posting a question?

Answer (score 0):

Personally i suggest using a framework to make your gifs here is the one i used. Just look through the read me it should help you, https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage